# Transform many squares into circles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I would like to create a highly stylized QR code. Namely, I want to transform all of the squares into circles (diameter = square width).

### Question

Does Illustrator have a built-in means for a task like this? For the isolated squares, it doesn't seem too daunting, but when many squares are stacked together, it creates a solid irregular shape which seems to pose a greater challenge.

The file I'd be working with is a .PNG exactly like the one below, not an existing .AI file.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Menu File** > **Place** > place the image in an Illustrator document
- Select the image
- **Menu Object** > **Create Object Mosaic** > **Number of Tiles** = the same number of squares the image has (63x63)
- Deselect the image and select it again
- **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- **Menu Effect** > **Convert to Shape** > **Ellipse** > **Absolute** = the small square size

[image: Ellipse]

### Result

[image: Result]

Comment: @Daniello wow! that's a powerful technique, many thanks!